# Photo currently in Figma file - how to use it for print / Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, photography, figma

I'm looking to print a photo as part of Illustrator Artwork I'm creating - the photo is currently in a Figma file, though, and I see that I cannot export it in TIFF format.

What would be the best way to move the photo in Figma to Illustrator for print?

Thanks

Comment: Right click the image in Figma and use *Copy/Paste as > Copy as PNG*. Then you can paste it into Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to right click to copy it as PNG, there is this [Plugin](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/973190386632562805/Export-Original-Images)